# How to use List<T> or Dictionary<T,T2> in C# WinRT component

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to create a C# WinRT component for use in metro style applications (win8) and am having trouble with projected types.

It seems the IVector<> and IMap<> data types are inaccessible due to their protection level?

My Sample WinMD Library has one class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public sealed class Class1
    {
        public IVector<string> foo()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following compiler errors:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVector<string>' is less accessible than method 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.foo()'

'Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVector<string>' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Ah ha!

Turns out I should not be using the WinRT type names directly, but using their translated .NET names instead.

The correct code looks like this:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public sealed class Class1
    {
        public IList<string> foo()
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a WinRT component which uses native APIs at it's core. So it needs to project List<T> -> IVector<T>. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301(v=vs.110).aspx for more details. The mapping table is about halfway down the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IIterable<T>` is projected to .NET as `IEnumerable<T>`, `IVector<T>` is projected as `IList<T>`, and `IMap<T>` is projected as `IDictionary<T>`. Projection goes both ways - both for consumption and for authoring - so you should simply always be using the projected versions of those interfaces in your .NET code. When you declare a member as returning `IList<T>`, it will show up as `IVector<T>` from WinRT perspective (e.g. from C++/CX). Similarly, if you implement `IDictionary` on your class, it'll show up as implementing `IMap` in C++/CX.

If I remember correctly, you should see all types already mapped as they should be when you use Object Browser for a .NET project.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the protection level errors I'm seeing.

Comment: Although not a direct answer to my question, you pointed me in the right direction. I've updated my post. Cheers!

Comment: I think I wasn't quite clear enough. The original `IVector` and stuff is there in .winmd (hence those protection level errors), you're just not meant to use it directly, always using the substitution described instead. I'll update the answer for others who come here via search.

Comment: Some relevant links from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230301.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700103.aspx.

Comment: Note that in practice things are a bit more complex than this answer implies: you create a `Vector<T>` in C++/CX which then gets projects as an `IList<T>` in C#. Or you create a `List<T>` in C# which gets projected as a `IVector<T>` in C++/CX. You can't create an `IVector<T>` or an `IList<T>`.